# Is Indra grammatically irregular?

Tags: sanskrit, sandhi

I came across this on http://sanskritdictionary.com/:

> <sup>kubera</sup> **kuberaḥ, yakṣarāṭ, yakṣendraḥ, yakṣeśvaraḥ, tryambakasakhā, guhyakeśvaraḥ, manuṣyadharmā, dhanadaḥ, dhanādhipaḥ, kinnareśaḥ, vaiśravaṇaḥ, paulastyaḥ, naravāhanaḥ, ekapiṅgaḥ, aiḍaviḍaḥ, śrīdaḥ, puṇyajaneśvaraḥ** `NOUN`
>
> yakṣānāṃ rājā yaḥ indrasya kośādhyakṣaḥ asti।
>
> > kuberaḥ rāvaṇasya bhrātā āsīt।

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Is Indra grammatically irregular, so the "n," does not transform like normal? If so it would make his names easier to pronounce.

I also asked this here:
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/43148/is-indra-grammatically-irregular

Edit: Text of screenshot by Severus Snape

Comment: What do you mean by “transform like normal”? Apart from containing the genitive of the name _Indra_ in the quote, I don’t see what the image has to do with your question. Also, despite what the comment to your question on Hinduism said, questions about the grammar of specific, individual languages is unfortunately considered off-topic here on [linguistics.se].

Comment: See the final rule in this: https://ubcsanskrit.ca/lesson3/sandhirules.html. A regular word would have the "n" transform.

Comment: Do you mean that the *n* न should become retroflex *ṇ* ण? If so, there's no reason that would happen in this word, as it isn't preceded by any of the sounds that trigger that rule.

Comment: The sibilant ṣ/ष्, triggers the transformation according to  ubcsanskrit.ca/lesson3/sandhirules.html.

Comment: https://www.sanskrit-trikashaivism.com/en/learning-sanskrit-combination-rules-of-sandhi-1/435, which gives the rules in their more complete forms agrees.

Comment: Sorry, my brain was on backwards for that preceding comment (now deleted). The rule is that /n/ becomes retroflex /ɳ/ if one of the retroflex consonants /ʂ ɽ/ (plus a few others) comes _before_ the /n/ in the same word. In _Indra_, there are no other consonants at all before the /n/, so the rule does not apply. Where are you getting the sibilant /ʂ/ from? There’s no such sound in _Indra_.

Comment: Indra on its own does not meet the criteria. Yakṣendra, which is Yakṣa + Indra (The Yakṣa Indra) does. Putting Indra after the race (or sub race) name is how the Indra of a race is shown, e.g Daityendra (Prahlāda), Pakṣī(n?)dra (Garuḍa, I don't know which nasal as the transliteration is unclear), Bhujagendra (Vāsuki),   etc.

Comment: This is because internal sandhi rules don't usually apply across elements of a compound.

Comment: They mostly do (such as Rāmāyaṇa). However, on further inspection, I found they don't for Tatpuruṣa compounds ubcsanskrit.ca/lesson14/samasa3.html . Since the Tatpuruṣa-ness is unlikely to come from Yakṣendra, since it is Yakṣa + Indra, which is a simple combination I think. This seems to imply Indra is a Tatpuruṣa compound to begin with, which begs the question a compound of what, but answers the original question

Comment: *Indra* itself is pretty clearly not a compound. I believe *Rāmāyaṇa* is an exception to the usual rule, but I don't have any references handy.

Comment: Actually, this source: https://www.jstor.org/stable/41694367?seq=1 suggests Indra could come from the root ind, so could be a compound of Ind and Ra (usually this is a suffix, but it could be its own word in theory). Thus, if it was compounded as a Tatpuruṣa, it would explain the weirdness. Not saying that is the meaning of Indra, just a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

The rule applies to /n/ only when immediately followed by a vowel or /n m y v/. In Indra, grantha etc. /n/ is followed by the wrong kind of segment, therefore the rule is inapplicable, regardless of the question of compounding.

Comment: Where is that restriction from? This site with the rules elaborated upon shows no such restriction: https://www.sanskrit-trikashaivism.com/en/learning-sanskrit-combination-rules-of-sandhi-1/435. Also, grantha is already irregular, unless it is a Tatpuruṣa as well, as the "n," should transform into either " Anusvāra" or " Anusvāra + s," depending on if it is at the word or not. (Use control f and "n" to find the relevant rules quickly.)

Comment: It's in Whitney's Sanskrit Grammar (the standard English reference grammar). Try to locate any example of /n/ changing before /t th d dh.

Comment: Interesting. I will check it out.

Comment: Wait. Any appearance of n immediately before those examples has to be irregular or a  Tatpuruṣa compound otherwise a previous rule of Sandhi would trigger first and transform it into either " Anusvāra" or " Anusvāra + s," meaning internal Sandhi can't apply to them, but not because of a rule by itself, just because of the interactions of the rules of Sandhi.

Comment: Thus, regardless of internal Sandhi Indra has to be irregular or a Tatpuruṣa compound. That ties up my original question neatly. Thanks for the reference though.